# php and js -> html encoding when importing a file

Tags: javascript, php, html, encoding, character-encoding

I'm using a picker that have lots of translations already done in .js format (https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/tree/master/lib/translations). 
So I imported them like 
`file_get_contents("../lib/translations/fr_FR.js")`

When printing I get :
`monthsFull: 
[ &#039;Janvier&#039;, &#039;Février&#039;, &#039;Mars&#039;, &#039;Avril&#039;, &#039;Mai&#039;, &#039;Juin&#039;`,

and not :

`monthsFull: [ 'Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre' ],`

So based on researched on stack overflow, I was hopping those methods will help me :

`mb_convert_encoding, iconv...` nothing worked!

Maybe I should use something else than `file_get_contents` ?

Comment: Try running `echo file_get_contents(<filename>)` in the CLI and check what it prints. This doesn't look like it has anything to do with multi-byte characters (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Unicode). It seems that the contents are written as http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php so you could probably just do `html_entity_decode` to get them back.

Comment: sorry no I already try it.

Comment: I've tried `echo file_get_contents('bs_BA.js');` on the `php -a` CLI and the output looked normal to me. Are you doing anything special with the output before returning it?

Comment: hello sorry guys PHP side it's ok, I'm using TWIG as template renderer and on the view it's giving the encoding problem...

Comment: Ok, found, I should add "raw"   {{myValue | raw }} to the view

Comment: You could probably answer your question with what you're doing (make sure to note the tempting engine you're using) and note what you've done to fix the issue and accept your answer. It may help other people if you do.